# String truncated at 255 chars when got from a MS Access SQL query

Tags: sql, vba, string, ms-access

I'm having problems with a String var in which I put a SQL query I've saved in MS Access. It works like this:

- I generate a list through a SELECT query
- Using a menu at a Userform with Excel VBA, I choose columns to order the list
- As I will have to order many lists in many ways, I decided to create a Sub `ordenar(ByVal sqlLista As String, ByVal sqlOrd As String)`.
- sqlLista contains the name of the `SELECT` query that generates the list I want to order; sqlOrd contains the `ORDER BY <col1>`... piece of query:

sqlLista = "ListaAbonos"

```
ListaAbonos (Access  query) = 

SELECT Left('0000',4-Len(c.nro_cliente)) & c.nro_cliente & ' - ' & IIF(IsNull(razon_social),apellido & ' ' & nombre, razon_social), a.cod_localidad & '/' & cod_cobrador, cod_abono, descripcion, tel_verificacion, fecha_alta, a.direccion, s.nombre_servicio, ts.valor, a.estado 
FROM ((abonos AS a 
INNER JOIN servicios AS s ON a.cod_servicio = s.cod_servicio) 
INNER JOIN tarifas_servicio AS ts ON a.cod_servicio = ts.cod_servicio) 
INNER JOIN clientes AS c ON a.nro_cliente = c.nro_cliente;

sqlOrd = "ORDER BY..."
```

[NOTE: I ran the entire query (SELECT...ORDER BY...) and *IT WORKS PROPERLY*]

**DECLARATIONS**

```
Public Sub ordenar(ByVal sqlLista As Variant, ByVal sqlOrd As Variant)

Dim cs As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sql As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
```

**CONNECTION TO DB:**

```
sPath = "C:\Users\Ezequiel\Documents\ZEN.accdb"
cs = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sPath & ";Persist Security Info=False;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open cs

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenStatic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
End With
```

**THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART OF THE CODE:**

```
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(sqlLista)
sql = Left(qd.sql, Len(qd.sql) - 1) & " " & sqlOrd
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
```

When I execute the Sub, I get an error

> Characters found after end of sql statement

Inspecting "sql" and "qd.sql" I found that the query had been truncated:

```
sql = qd.sql = "SELECT Left('0000',4-Len(c.nro_cliente)) & c.nro_cliente & ' - ' & IIF(IsNull(razon_social),apellido & ' ' & nombre, razon_social), a.cod_localidad & '/' & cod_cobrador, cod_abono, descripcion, tel_verificacion, fecha_alta, a.direccion, s.nombre_serv
```

Note that the ORDER BY doesn't even appear as it's beyond the first 255 chars.

What's the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the sql (after removing the semi colon) and order by?

Comment: Just tried that but I still get the error. It is theorically correct as the semi colon has to be removed, but inspecting the variables, I get the exact same truncated string.

Comment: Can you debug.print sqllista?  Is it truncated?